MongoDB replace multiple character with one in embedded document
I have a document in MongoDB having this structure:
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "66792ac155b1a3e359fe8626"
  },
  "main_project_id": {
    "$oid": "65d37b3c9b23a29ac1f5dc37"
  },
  "project_id": 82492,
  "form_details": {
    "Field1": 82492,
    "Field2": "XXX",
    "Field3": "Inline",
    ....
  },
  "item": {
    "01.01": 770232,
    "01.01.01": 61400,
    "01.01.02": 8882.85,
    "01@03": 0,
  }
}]

At the moment i'm able to create a view that find a point in the item keys and replace it with an underscore, as follows:
db.createCollection(
  "costSummaryView",
  {
    "viewOn" : "costSummary",
    "pipeline" : [{
    $set: {
      "item": {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$item" },
            in: {
              k: {
                $replaceAll: {
                    input: "$$this.k",
                    find: ".",
                    replacement: "_",
                }
              },
              v: "$$this.v"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  }
)

Now i'm finding a solution to find either a point and @ character to replace them both with an underscore, i tried this solution, but it doesn't work:
db.createCollection(
  "costSummaryView",
  {
    "viewOn" : "costSummary",
    "pipeline" : [{
    $set: {
      "item": {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$item" },
            in: {
              k: {
                $replaceAll: {
                  input: "$$this.k",
                  find: ".",
                  replacement: "_"
                },
              },
              v: "$$this.v"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "item": {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$item" },
            in: {
              k: {
                $replaceAll: {
                  input: "$$this.k",
                  find: "@",
                  replacement: "_"
                },
              },
              v: "$$this.v"
            }
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }],
  }
)

Is there a way to replace multiple characters?

You can't mention the same field "item" in the same stage twice. Here, you're trying to $set the "item" twice. Either do it in two $set stages (easier) like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/la_V9HagPu5 or nested like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/J9Zz-Zw8kba. I find the two stages option better, even if a bit verbose, to avoid further unreadable nesting for the next thing you want to replace.

Ok it works like a charm, thank you!!
